# ActiveRecord::ImmutableRelation in rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In controller:

```
def update     
@dtmRealshow= DateTime.parse(params[:showtime][:dtmRealshow].to_s).strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p") 
@showtime.update(:dtmRealshow=> @dtmRealshow,:theatre_id=>params[:showtime][:theatre_id],:city_id=>params[:showtime][:city_id],:movie_id=>params[:showtime][:movie_id])
@showtimes = Showtime.all.order(:created_at).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 8)
end
```

In `_index.html.erb`:

```
<% @showtimes.each do |showtime| %>          
-------------------------

<% end %>
<%= will_paginate @showtimes%>
```

In `update.js.erb`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#divShow').html("<%= j (render 'showtimes/index') %>");
$('#myModal').modal('hide');
$('#notice').html("Showtime is successfully updated.").show();
});
```

In my application I am using will_paginate gem.After update a record I am getting `http://localhost:3000/showtimes/45?page=4` URL when clicked on the pagination. I want to remove the `id=45` because it causes error.

Comment: If you want to include code segments as blocks, copy them in (without tabs), select the block and hit Ctlr+K.

Comment: After putting the pagination in the index page.....it works.